# How to dump memory of virtual machine running in linux?

Tags: forensics, virtualization, memory

I have a windows virtual machine installed using qemu. I want to know how can I dump the entire ram memory of guest system from host system like *bin2dmp* do in windows. I have read [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20334/memory-dumping-cause-for-concern-in-virtualization) that it is possible but not able find out how to do that. So any help with that will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45397607/1974978 You may also be able to suspend the VM and simply read the ram out of the dump file that is automatically created.

Comment: Have you tried using `pmemsave`?

Comment: Thanks, I will try `pmemsave` which is also mentioned on the link commented by @multithr3at3d and will update you if get successful.